# Is it possible to pass Argumentlist from WinForms VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments

I can pass Argumentlist in a console app as below

```
Public Class test
  Public myProcess As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo

    Sub Main()
        With myProcess

            .FileName = <<some path>>
            For Each x As String In <<some list>>
                .Argumentlist.add(x)
            Next
            WorkingDirectory = args
            .UseShellExecute = False
        End With
    End Sub
End class
```

But when working in a WinForms project, I can't access the .argumentList and can only access .arguments :(

Answer (score 0):

> I can pass Argumentlist in a console app as below

I don't think so. There is no `ArgumentList` property anywhere that I can see. When you use `Process.Start`, you basically just replicate what you would do if you were to use a console window. If you were to start an app like this in a console window:

> MyApp -a \b "C:\Some Folder\Some File.ext"

then you basically just reproduce that in code. The *MyApp* part is the `FileName` and the rest is the `Arguments`:

```vb
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("MyApp", "-a \b ""C:\Some Folder\Some File.ext""")
```

If you have a list of arguments then you simply join them into a single, space-separated `String`:

```vb
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("MyApp", String.Join(" ", myArgumentList))
```

EDIT:

The `ArgumentList` property referred to is only supported in .NET Core, not in .NET Framework. That it was available in a Console Application project had nothing to do with the project type specifically but rather the targeted platform. If you target .NET Framework in a Console Application project then that property will not be available either and if you target .NET Core in a Windows Forms Application project (which you can't do in VB just yet, although you can for C#) then that property would be available there too.

You really ought to learn the difference between .NET Core, which is relatively new, and .NET Framework, which has been there from the start, and make sure that you are targeting the correct option in all your projects. It will be less of an issue when .NET 5.0 is released. I'm not sure of all the details but they are basically merging .NET Core and .NET Framework in that version.

In the end, the solution I have provided is what you need to do when targeting .NET Framework 4.8 or earlier, regardless of the project type.

Comment: [ArgumentList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.argumentlist?view=netcore-3.1) this is how I used the argumentList that I mentioned here. List was a lot easier as I could just '.add' new arguments and avoid any string manipulation.

Comment: thanks for that. I've used string manipulation for now which does what I want :)